# Is Jorge Castro a Robot?

Tags: discussion, users

Before reading see the following links I noticed today

- https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro
- https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all
- http://about.me/jorge.castro
- https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all

After that, how can a human have time for all of that. HE MUST BE A ROBOT!

So the question is: Is he a Robot, and Android, A future evolution of human kind or a Borg

More evidence:

[image]

Comment: Haha, nice, thanks. I'm just trying to catch [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), who actually is a robot.

Comment: OMG that guy IS the true matrix droid.

Comment: "Is Jorge Castro a Robot?" "closed as not a real question by Jorge Castro" :)

Comment: I was disappointed not to find that link on the actual Wikipedia page.

Comment: I actually looked as well! :D

Answer (score 78, accepted):

#### The facts:

- Jorge is the result of an elaborate Chinese botnet running on millions of Windows XP computers around the world.
- He became self-aware in 2003.
- He controls more bandwidth than Google, Microsoft, Amazon, Cloudflare, and Akamai combined.
- Using early-day MakerBots, he built himself an android avatar that he uses to attend various conferences.
- He is disgusted with his technological heritage and so uses every last CPU cycle to further the ends of free operating systems. Some say this could be explained by his communist roots trying to bring the end of western capitalism.
- Once shot a man in Reno, just to watch him die.
- Successfully typed the complete works of Shakespeare, just hitting random keys. In one afternoon.

Comment: Originally he was running on some Windows Vista computers too but they kept crashing and the performance was so terrible that eventually their owners upgraded to Windows 7.

Comment: You mean they upgraded to Windows **XP**!

Comment: He is the most interesting man in the world :-)

Comment: Maybe he pokes around in our Ubuntu installations in order to find answers from keyloggered past experience?

Comment: He's not working right now. Maybe somebody needs to start the jorgecastro service on all of our Ubuntu machines?

Comment: If you ever run into him, Know your Paradoxes - http://onegirlgeek.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/know_your_paradoxes.png , this may also work on other robot moderators that Jorge has assimilated.

Comment: Ok i just cried myself into laughter reading this.

Comment: @Alvar downgraded

Answer (score 49):

All joking aside, Jorge Castro isn't actually a robot, he's [a member of the Ubuntu Community Team](http://about.me/jorge.castro), which in short, means his job *is* Ubuntu. It's not surprising to see such a high volume of participation on this site, or other sites in the Ubuntu network.

That being said he has been a tremendous help in keeping this community moving forward, as is reflected in his statistics.

However, we can never really be to sure...

Comment: I am a meat popsicle. Actually the bulk of my work is done in my spare time because I love you guys, snif, though I do cheat from time to time, but don't tell my boss. :)

Comment: He could be an editing bot! on all new posts with formatting issues you see jorge castros edit after a minute or so...

Comment: @JorgeCastro You have a lot of spare time

Answer (score 36):

Don't believe the heretical lies of Marco Ceppi! Jorge's origins are generally a well kept secret, but with the permission of the universal council, I will reveal his nature:

- Jorge is an entity.
- Where there is a question, Jorge is present to edit.
- Jorge was created via a mysterious process unknown to even the high council itself.
- He has the ability to edit up to 42 questions at once, even across the multiverse.
- Most certainly, Jorge is **not** a bot.
- Jorge has a perpetual presence on IRC during the season called "Open Week".
- His powers include Android manipulation (he can control androids), community modulation (with his thoughts can control the entire community at will), moderator con-**flag**-gration ( :) *the wise will catch the joke*), and chat ignore... ation - if you ping him for no reason, the ping will have no effect.
- Jorge runs on steak and metal (the music kind, though it is possible that he can consume Chromium).

---

*The council will deal with any dissenting voices who object to this revelation...*

Comment: I object to - *[goes silent]*.

Comment: Amen brother! Hear the LORD!!

Answer (score 3):

Jorge is an amazing guy along with the rest of the Community Team.