# Found a bug /exploit in the data from askubuntu.com?

Tags: discussion, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Jorge Castro a Robot?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1900/is-jorge-castro-a-robot)

The user page reports strange values that cannot be true for a normal human, I suspect a hacker or a bot. Beware :)!

[image]