# What are common canonical questions for our site?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, canonical-questions

So according to [the Gospel of Spolsky 13:4](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/), a core mission of Stack Exchange communities is to stop re-answering the same questions, and instead build a library of canonical answers. When general duplicates (instances of a problem) arise, we close and refer them to one such answer. For example:

> [bisig PPA causing 404 error?](https://askubuntu.com/q/19170/24694) -> [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

That said, many times on the [review tab](https://askubuntu.com/review/) I see the same issues popping up, over and over... but don't know where to find the canonical question I know must exist! And should it not exist, that I know that we must *make* exist. Partial Upgrade errors anyone?

---

Please list common canonical questions that you know of in the following format. *You can also answer with canonical questions you think **should** exist.*

> #### [Is Jorge Castro a Robot?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1900/is-jorge-castro-a-robot)
>
> **Examples:** [How does Jorge Castro have so many badges?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/-1/not-an-actual-question-yet), [I shook hands with a guy at UDS. Why was his hand cold and rubbery?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/-1/not-an-actual-question-yet), [whiprush on internet - biology uncertainty](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/-1/not-an-actual-question-yet)
>
> **Queries:** `[if any, list data.stackexchange.com duplicate searches here]`

Template:

```
### QUESTION_URL_HERE

**Examples:** DUPLICATE_URL_HERE, DUPLICATE_URL_HERE [and so on]

**Queries:** DATA_QUERY_HERE [omit this line if no query exists]
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning our bot :p

Comment: I could see this page quickly growing out of control. There has to be a better way to maintain this information — dare I suggest a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)?

Comment: I assumed moderators had a list somewhere that they passed around for such things.  Is this not so?  Is this question on meta meant to create such a list?

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh As I explained on chat, this is the canonical list. mods (like normal users) can (and do) maintain a personal list, but it's generally very specific.

Comment: I added a proposed bracket. I think desired, proposed, and accepted should all have lists.

Comment: Dare I suggest to categorize the proposed questions (as they have [done in TEX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2419/31685)), and not to restrict the list to "how to"s? I think it would be useful to have also readily available links to things like "[What is a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/q/4983/58950)" and such.

Answer (score 22):

## Existing canonical questions:

- #### [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736)

  **Examples:** [What is the best Ubuntu version for my hp tc4200 netbook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333535/what-is-the-best-ubuntu-version-for-my-hp-tc4200-netbook) , [What are the Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit desktop system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332722/what-are-the-ubuntu-13-04-32-bit-desktop-system-requirements), I have X hardware, what version you recommend me?, I am chinese! What version of Ubuntu should I install?, I want to setup a SmartTV, what I need? Plenty of them

---

- #### [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

  **Examples:** *Many...*

---

- #### [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

  **Examples:** [bisig PPA causing 404 error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19170/bisig-ppa-causing-404-error)

---

- #### [I can't boot into a usable system after updates. What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-anymore-what-should-i-do)

  **Examples:**  [Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128584/upgrade-from-11-10-to-1204-failed), https://askubuntu.com/questions/126756/my-ubuntu-is-broken-help

---

- #### [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

  **Examples:** [How to migrate from Wubi to a regular installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27988/how-to-migrate-from-wubi-to-a-regular-installation)

---

- #### [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34430/24694)

  **Examples:** [Can I upgrade from 10.04 to 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92119/can-i-upgrade-from-10-04-to-11-10), [Now that 11.04 is out will 10.04 still upgrade to 10.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37612/now-that-11-04-is-out-will-10-04-still-upgrade-to-10-10), [Update 11.04 to 12.04 with LiveCD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125600/update-11-04-to-12-04-with-livecd)

---

- #### ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)

  **Examples:** [Apt-get packages "kept back"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125645/apt-get-packages-kept-back), [Natty Alpha Testing "Kept Back" Updates, Ubuntu or My System?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21412/natty-alpha-testing-kept-back-updates-ubuntu-or-my-system)

---

- #### [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

  **Examples:** [How do I change fonts & icons in a theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59919/how-do-i-change-fonts-icons-in-a-theme), [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

---

- #### [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/fixing-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock)

  **Examples:** [Installation Error, "Unable to lock the administration directory"](https://askubuntu.com/q/99537/24694), https://askubuntu.com/questions/122923/cannot-install-skype-due-to-error-var-lib-dpkg-lock-error

---

- #### [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

  **Examples:** [BADSIG error while updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94249/badsig-error-while-updating)

---

- #### [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

  **Examples:** [GIMP Package broken, Ubuntu Software centre not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96420/gimp-package-broken-ubuntu-software-centre-not-working), [Broken package error after updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25761/broken-package-error-after-updating)

---

- #### [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/176889)

  **Examples:** [How do I Dual Boot Windows 8 UEFI and Ubuntu 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219027/how-do-i-dual-boot-windows-8-uefi-and-ubuntu-12-10?lq=1), [Boot manager is showing \Ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr is missing or contains error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215661/boot-manager-is-showing-ubuntu-winboot-wubildr-mbr-is-missing-or-contains-error?lq=1)

---

- #### [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

  **Examples:** [Run shell script on startup or boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108800/),
  [Run script at boot/startup in Ubuntu 12.04 x64 Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308993/),
  [How To Run An Application On Startup Automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442246/)

---

- #### [How do I improve boot speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed)

  Countless examples

---

- #### [My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to)

  **Examples:** [Can't upgrade due to low disk space on /boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142926/)
  [apt-get: No space left on device (12.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317763)
  [0 bytes left on /boot, apt autoremove and apt --fix-broken install fail due to unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410549/)

---

- #### [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

  **Examples:**  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418244/how-to-fix-these-errors-during-boot, [Strange messages on startup after the latest update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418222/strange-messages-on-startup-after-the-latest-update), [Multiple errors when booting ubuntu (SGX disabled by BIOS among others)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418139/multiple-errors-when-booting-ubuntu-sgx-disabled-by-bios-among-others), [BIOS ACPI error when dual booting Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418135/bios-acpi-error-when-dual-booting-ubuntu-22-04), [Can someone explain/help me understand/solve this ACPI error bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417480/can-someone-explain-help-me-understand-solve-this-acpi-error-bug), [Ubuntu boot ACPI error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417209/ubuntu-boot-acpi-error), [Ubuntu firmware bug on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416767/ubuntu-firmware-bug-on-boot), [When I turn on my desktop, every time showing some error [ Ubuntu 22.04 ]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405225/when-i-turn-on-my-desktop-every-time-showing-some-error-ubuntu-22-04), [ACPI error messages during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367947/acpi-error-messages-during-boot), [how do I fix an ACPI error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407739/how-do-i-fix-an-acpi-error), [Error messages at boot, what they mean and how can I fix them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360648/error-messages-at-boot-what-they-mean-and-how-can-i-fix-them)

---

- #### [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

  **Examples:**  many

---

- #### [No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911865/no-more-disk-space-how-can-i-find-what-is-taking-up-the-space)

  **Examples:**  many

---

- #### [What are phased updates, and why does Ubuntu use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them)

  **Examples:**  many

---

- #### [What are ESM Apps, and how do they relate to Ubuntu Pro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452497/what-are-esm-apps-and-how-do-they-relate-to-ubuntu-pro)

  **Examples:**  [Extended Security Maintenance (ESM) for focal fossa (20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325365/extended-security-maintenance-esm-for-focal-fossa-20-04), [Why am I getting ESM updates 1 year into a LTS release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453597/why-am-i-getting-esm-updates-1-year-into-a-lts-release/)

---

## Desired canonical questions:

- #### How to fix "connected" wireless but no working internet?

  **Examples:** https://askubuntu.com/questions/180476/,
  https://askubuntu.com/questions/180512/,
  [Wireless Connected But No Internet Connection (Ubuntu 12.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150212/)

---

- #### How do I diagnose fan problems?

  Possibly multiplexes into other questions for specific, common hardware configurations.

---

- #### How to fix partial upgrades error?

  Common, fairly annoying.

---

- #### How to boot after failed Kernel upgrade

  [kernel update failed using apt-get dist-upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61166/kernel-update-failed-using-apt-get-dist-upgrade),
  [How Can I Roll Back a Kernel Update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57937/how-can-i-roll-back-a-kernel-update)

---

- #### How to fix getting text mode when rebooting after install?

  https://askubuntu.com/questions/135895/i-get-a-command-prompt-on-rebooting-after-install-what-should-i-do

---

- #### Installing Ubuntu failed. What should I do?

  Countless examples

---

- #### How do I swap / remap keys?

  A variety of cases. System-wide versus application-specific.  Swapping keys or altering the layout in some way.  Solutions also differ.  There are DE-specific solutions and general X-windows solutions.  Sometimes these conflict, causing their own issues.

---

- #### The system has frozen up, although the mouse still works.  What should I do?

  Pointless to just tell them to file a bug, because ubuntu-bug alone doesn't capture the right information.  There are specific troubleshooting steps to do in order to collect the required information, but what to do is also driver-specific.  The Ubuntu-X freeze troubleshooting guide in the wiki is a good reference but users often need some additional hand-holding and encouragement.

---

- #### The session terminated and left me at the login screen.  What do I do?

  Basically, need a full backtrace collected via gdb; apport is *supposed* to collect this but in cases where it's come to a question, it probably has failed to do so.  The Ubuntu-X Backtrace wiki page walks the user through how to do this manually but can be intimidating for less technically oriented folks.

---

- #### My screen went blank and I can't turn it back on.  What do I do?

  The symptoms for "black screen bugs" are always indistinguishably similar, but the underlying causes are quite varied. There are several dozen different distinct causes for blank screens, and it's worthless to guess based merely on reported symptoms.  But simply filing a bug report is not usually enough either, since you need to look at the status of things both before and after to spot differences.  The Ubuntu-X wiki pages have some guides on what to do here, but most users need extra hand-holding.

---

- #### I upgraded and something stopped working right.  How do I narrow down what exactly broke?

  Package bisection search time.  /var/log/dpkg.log to the rescue!

---

- #### I want to uninstall "program X" but I get a warning that my desktop will be deleted.

  Examples:

  - [lubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/q/233662/25656)
  - [xubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/q/235897/25656)

Comment: What about my "How to port Ubuntu Touch to xyz device?" question - do you want that in this list?

Comment: I guess Canonical questions are useful if:
1) They provide links to as many related questions as possible (with the possibility of permanent update by users), as "Existing canonical questions" here;
2) They get listed high in searches (Google, StackExchange, etc.), so users can have it as a "reference index".
Item #2 does not seem to happen, so I am not seeing this list very useful, as of today.
Can this be worked out?

Answer (score 5):

Needed:

- I broke my system by messing about with python. How do I fix it?
- I used the directions on a website to install wine and broke my system. How do I fix it?
- Pending Update of Snap Store / canonical answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1412580/243321
- Why are packages being held back when I do an update / because of phased updates

Comment: [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/q/384033/) For "I used the directions on a website to install Wine and broke my system" it depends on the error message. There are two main categories of questions: 1. questions that contain a "you have held broken packages" error message and 2. all other questions that don't contain this error message. There are 4 or 5 questions that I use as duplicate questions for close voting Wine questions depending on the error message.

Comment: Yep. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394574/getting-errors-with-apt-update) for another example of "I messed with Python and broke my system"

Answer (score 3):

I added a proposed bracket.  I think desired, proposed, and accepted should all have lists.

## Proposed

Example suitable duplicate: [How to deal with a frozen screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151049/how-to-deal-with-a-frozen-screen)
Proposed canonical answer:
[What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Rationale:
Different than, How do I file a bug?, How do I troubleshoot what is crashing?,
and their ilk, but has a good detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking, do we have a Canonical answer for how to safely remove Ubuntu from a Double/Multi-boot? That would be useful I believe.

Comment: There likely already exists a answer along the lines of "boot off live CD, delete ubuntu partition, and reformat, or re-size the windows partition to over take the space."

Answer (score 0):

If we're in dupe or merge mode, this should probably be incorporated: [Finding questions that other questions have been closed as a dupe of](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3317/finding-questions-that-other-questions-have-been-closed-as-a-dupe-of/3370#3370)

Just saying, a list question that is unmaintainable is not a script that is maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Another CQ below.

There are different causes and solutions for this problem (and most likely for other CQs as well).
But I guess what could be considered "Canonical" is the initial set of actions, commands to try, information to post in a prospective new question.
This should be brought to attention immediately for anyone asking, I guess.
See also [this comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3053/what-are-common-canonical-questions-for-our-site#comment43145_3073).

#### [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul)

**Examples:** (out of the tons [here](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=dummy%20output))

[Ubuntu 19.04 dummy output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144663/ubuntu-19-04-dummy-output) ,
[Output device is dummy output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218413/output-device-is-dummy-output) ,
[Ubuntu 21.04 dummy output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345902/ubuntu-21-04-dummy-output) ,
[Persistent Dummy Output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800262/persistent-dummy-output) ,
[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS dummy output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222089/ubuntu-18-04-lts-dummy-output) ,
[Ubuntu 19.10 Dummy Output error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219889/ubuntu-19-10-dummy-output-error) ,
[No audio output in 18.04. Only output device is 'dummy output'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273465/no-audio-output-in-18-04-only-output-device-is-dummy-output) ,
[Dummy Output after upgrade to 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837472/dummy-output-after-upgrade-to-16-10) ,
[Sound stopped working, "dummy output"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843745/sound-stopped-working-dummy-output) ,
[Dummy Output Sound Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218771/dummy-output-sound-error) ,
[Dummy Output help required](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357502/dummy-output-help-required) ,
[Dummy output, no soundcard detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329442/dummy-output-no-soundcard-detected) ,
[Dummy output for sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332456/dummy-output-for-sound) ,
[Dummy Output Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320660/dummy-output-ubuntu-20-04) ,
...