# Finding questions that other questions have been closed as a dupe of

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicates

Is there a way to find questions with a high closed as dupe points here count?

If there were, I think it would be a great way to get a list of questions for people with close-votes without as much digging.

It would also allow easier canonical question/answer transitions.

Comment: If the system does store this information in an accessible manner, perhaps we could add a badge for having a question with more than some number of duplicates (*that you did not yourself create*).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usage: `./dupes.sh posts.xml`
Yields: `./dupes.txt`
when applied to the latest data dump.

dupes.sh

```
#/bin/bash
cat $1 | grep ' ClosedDate\=\"' | grep 'Possible Duplicate' | awk -F 'Possible Duplicate:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br&gt;&#xA;  &lt;a href=&quot;' '{print $2}' | awk -F '&quot;&gt;' '{print $1}' | grep questions > dupes.txt  
python dupes.py
```

dupes.py

```
lines = []
with open('dupes.txt', 'r') as dupeList:
    for line in dupeList.readlines():
        lines.append(line.rstrip())

links = {}
for line in lines:
    try:
        links[line] += 1
    except:
        links[line] = 1
thelinks = []
for link in links.keys():
    thelinks.append((link, links[link]))

thelinksort = sorted(thelinks, key=lambda alink: alink[1])

thelinksort.reverse()

with open('dupes.txt', 'w') as dupeList:
    for line in thelinksort:
        dupeList.write('Link: ' + line[0] + ' Count: ' + str(line[1]) + '\n')
```

Here's the list of all questions duped more than 3 times sorted in descending order by number of dupes:

```
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do Count: 100
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears Count: 27
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic Count: 23
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher Count: 19
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline Count: 18
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/problem-with-mergelist-error-when-trying-to-do-an-update Count: 18
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme Count: 18
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work Count: 17
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors Count: 14
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password Count: 13
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey Count: 11
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-etype-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update Count: 11
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work Count: 10
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration Count: 10
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity Count: 10
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity Count: 10
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3 Count: 9
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast Count: 9
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size Count: 9
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell Count: 9
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd Count: 9
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity Count: 8
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/failed-to-download-package-files-error Count: 8
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/77487/how-to-fix-check-your-internet-connection-error-in-software-center Count: 8
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-upgraded-from-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-if-i-keep-upgrading Count: 8
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions Count: 8
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key Count: 8
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-switch-to-the-classic-gnome-desktop Count: 8
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there Count: 7
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-not-working Count: 7
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9865/how-can-i-configure-unitys-launcher-auto-hide-behavior Count: 7
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in Count: 7
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox Count: 7
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity Count: 7
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa Count: 7
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34182/can-i-edit-which-icons-appear-in-the-unity-dash Count: 7
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working Count: 6
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1 Count: 6
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do Count: 6
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu Count: 6
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37084/nvidia-driver-activated-but-currently-not-in-use Count: 6
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package Count: 6
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/does-unity-support-disabling-the-global-application-menu Count: 6
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools Count: 6
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-the-theme Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37083/how-can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-delay Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3 Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55253/how-safe-is-it-to-use-the-ubuntu1 Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29757/what-can-replace-system-monitoring-in-the-top-gnome-panel-in-unity Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-and-btrfs-partitions-in-windows Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35625/how-do-i-make-unity-remember-which-applications-are-in-the-launcher Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password Count: 5
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64968/how-do-i-enable-mp3-preview Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/deactivate-bluetooth-on-startup Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16874/boot-screen-in-low-graphics-text-mode Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64885/how-do-i-upgrade-from-11-04-to-11-10 Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14168/installer-gets-stuck-with-a-grayed-out-forward-button Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73482/problem-with-gnome3-shell-top-taskbar Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/44118/mouse-dead-zone-that-makes-it-impossible-to-click Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-upgraded-from-a-beta-am-i-now-running-the-official-non-development-version Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38028/performance-being-really-choppy-with-ati-drivers Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29969/is-there-a-unity-equivalent-of-the-gnome-panel-show-desktop-applet Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1148/what-is-the-best-place-to-install-user-apps Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-use-use-the-classic-gnome-desktop Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27410/migrating-from-evolution-to-thunderbird Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3678/make-my-own-dropbox-ubuntu-one-server-at-home Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37651/how-can-i-activate-unity Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5571/how-can-i-install-unity-after-installing-desktop-edition Count: 4
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7 Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/71359/where-is-open-with-in-nautilus Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2502/where-can-i-get-themes-and-eye-candy-for-my-desktop Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6588/visual-studio-style-tool Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/71139/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-on-11-10 Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73030/can-i-get-unity-style-super1-9-keyboard-shortcuts-for-launching-apps-in-gnome Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-lightdm-when-using-auto-logins Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62941/how-do-i-set-the-launcher-to-always-show-in-unity-2d Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85209/is-there-a-mac-osx-version-of-ubuntuone-planned-for-the-near-future Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracles-jdk-6 Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66786/how-to-disable-login-sound Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34214/how-do-i-disable-overlay-scrollbars Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/647/parental-controls-with-different-settings-for-different-users Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-to-make-ubuntu-boot-fast Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30882/how-do-i-make-the-dash-open-up-fullscreen-in-2d Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7377/how-to-start-an-app-with-always-on-top-set Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38789/remove-the-workspace-switcher-launcher-from-unity-launcher Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40571/how-to-keep-programs-from-launching-maximized Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups-gui Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37747/how-to-remove-apps-available-for-download-from-the-applications-lens Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/86586/accessing-windows-partition-inside-wubi Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-to-install-ubuntu Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16736/menu-missing-in-lotus-notes-8-and-eclipse-in-unity Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4497/workspace-specific-wallpapers-with-compiz Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/fixing-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63921/unity-3d-doesnt-work-anymore-just-shows-a-menu-on-the-top Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1090/why-is-defragmentation-unnecessary Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue-ubuntu-12-04-and-ubuntu-11-10 Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/247/whats-your-recommendation-on-drive-partitioning-schemes-for-a-desktop-and-home-s Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35076/how-do-i-whitelist-truecrypt-to-work-under-unity Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-installed-ubuntu Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53688/making-ctrlc-copy-text-in-gnome-terminal Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6422/how-to-distribute-windows-over-virtual-desktops-in-gnome Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25409/how-to-emulate-winkeyarrow-windows-7s-maximise-shortcut-keys Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-chose Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19792/duplicated-entries-in-ubuntu-one Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-des-and-shells-are-available Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43077/how-do-i-start-developing-a-lens-for-unity Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65803/two-battery-indicator-symbols-how-do-i-get-rid-of-one Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/how-to-make-gnome-remember-brightness-setting Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35715/how-to-install-firefox-3-6-and-4-0-in-parallel Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9817/battery-drain-on-ubuntu-is-fast Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13562/how-do-we-get-this-magic-performance-boosting-200-line-patch Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1441/why-not-use-64-bit-ubuntu Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9515/how-do-i-change-the-guest-session-defaults Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5435/will-there-be-data-loss-for-upgrade Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/90929/can-i-keep-using-ubuntu-9-04-if-its-outdated Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/difference-between-32bit-and-64-bit Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11993/how-do-i-install-bcm4312-wireless-drivers Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5466/is-a-clean-install-better-than-upgrading Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9890/will-unity-be-more-customizable Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-to-disable-x-at-boot-time Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-restore-default-video-drives Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62808/ati-incompatible-with-gnome-shell Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65476/when-will-the-upcoming-ubuntu-release-be-made-available Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79186/why-isnt-firefox-8-0-available-as-an-update-in-the-update-manager Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53202/how-do-you-create-a-new-document-keyboard-shortcut Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screen-savers Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-11-10-to-11-04 Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7 Count: 3
Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/108572/i-had-a-bunch-of-notes-in-my-account-where-did-they-go Count: 3
```