# Summer cleanup, feedback wanted, etc

Tags: discussion, tags

Basically, what I'd like to do is get community 'permission' to do the following over the next few weeks (for whats left of June, and then thereafter whenever I have time):

- Completely destroy and utterly eradicate the following tags:

  - [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error) **DONE.**
  - [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze)
  - [crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/crash)
  - [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug) **DONE.**
  - [slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/slow) **DONE.**
- Try and clean up our duplicates, primarily:

  - all those ["I can't login" questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=can%27t%20login).
  - [The 'unity is broken' ones](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D%20broken&submit=search).
  - Clean up [the low graphics mode ones](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=+low+graphics+mode&submit=search)
  - Any others the community thinks there might be a fair amount of.
- Hack my way through the latest data dump and close all those dupes that slipped through the cracks.

Why am I writing this? I mean, I'm a moderator, it's my *job* to intervene in situations like this, right?

- I'm proposing a massive undertaking. If I'm going to undertake something *this big* in a period of weeks (not months), I should have a stamp of community approval.
- Not only the above, but a little help now and then would be appreciated. ;)
- Lastly, while I *think* I'll have my plate full, I think having the community give me possible 'targets' for cleaning would be artificial.

> Why am I doing this *now*, instead of earlier? I mean, this would have been nice *during* the 12.04 release week!
>
> > Well, this summer I have a part time job, and no school. As such, I have 2-3 days a week to devote (as in, a 9-5 job) to doing stuff like this, so I'd like to get stuff done while I can (Making hay while the sun shines type thing).

If the community has any comments, please make them - I'm planning on going full speed ahead on June 11th (roughly).

I'd like to note **one more thing**: As I'm going through the three tags listed above, I **will** be closing them as bugs (so off-topic). I will leave comments. If people have a problem with that, lets talk about how I can make that "not a problem", either through peer review, a weekly list of all the ones I've taken action on, etc. However, since I've been accused of a 'shoot-first-ask-questions-later' mentality, I want to make this clear.

Comment: All I can say is - **go for it**!

Comment: I second the motion.

Comment: Why not an cleanup week?

Comment: @abcd We burned out most of our normal go-to people for cleanup with the last one, and then the 12.04 release week. I don't think we could reasonably ask people to do another one.

Comment: Can you also add the [slow] tag to that list

Comment: @YiJiang Done! :)

Comment: @jrg there are a lot more than just a few as mentioned above. Some tags have 1 or 2 questions attached and are related to others, more meaningful tags and questions which have long been answered or are not currently supported. The "Clean Team" needs more latitude than just voting. They need real super-powers to advocate change. Whatever your decision is, good luck.

Comment: @blueXrider Yes, there are many other tags. However, I'm starting with the big problems, and then I can trust that the community can handle the maintenance and the little tags.

Comment: will the tag `spilt` , `view` and `colors` fall in the cleanup category?

Comment: @Ashu those look small enough that I'll get to them if I have time, but it's not likely.

Comment: Go for it !!! :)

Comment: Yep. Go for it.

Comment: Are there any ways any of this could be automated via greasemonkey?  Does stackexchange have a programmatical API?

Comment: I think you'd be hard pushed to find anyone who wouldn't appreciate this. +1 from me.

Comment: @Bryce they have an API, however it is read-only. And the margin for error with automating this is uh, shall we say small enough that I don't want to do it.

Comment: As you are at it, also clean up the [unmet dependencies](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22unmet+dependencies%22&submit=search) questions.

Comment: And, why did we forget about the [tag:freeze] tag again??

Comment: @jokerdino simply because we forgot it? *groans*

Answer (score 9):

Just a suggestion but for questions that we see that start to create a duplicate ripple, why not create a question to rule them all. For example, for the [Low Graphics Mode](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%20low%20graphics%20mode&submit=search)
how about create a question that has most of the information gathered from all of the answers provided or a general step by step way to solve most problems related to it.

Same goes for slow, error and other tags. A single, community wiki question that has multiple answers that can answer most users, eventually helping out the moderators, the clean up done in the future and saving a lot of time. I could help with this if the community thinks is a good idea as well.

Comment: Creating canonical questions is really a important one - i think we've got one for the low graphics, but i'm not sure for others.

Comment: When I get home going to help with those 3. Was looking in how to use the search to provide better results.

Comment: @jrg can you provide the question that is already created which I can use to redirect duplicates to and to create better answers there. That way I don't need to create an additional question for this, just use an existing one.

Comment: I'd be very interested in helping ensure there is a good page with multiple answers for the low graphics mode issues.  If/when there's something sketched in please contact me and I'll help fill in answers.

Answer (score 9):

I thought a list of common dupes might be useful for your purposes.  I compiled one.

[Here's a pretty comprehensive list of common dupes from the April dump.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3317/finding-questions-that-other-questions-have-been-closed-as-a-dupe-of/3370#3370)

Answer (score 3):

Crash is also done. Given the volume and current wiki excerpt for [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze), I'm gonna let y'all work that out; ping me when you're done cleaning it up.

Comment: Crash reappeared and freeze is hot on his tail... :(