# Please blacklist the 'bug' tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

In regards to this, http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3343/summer-cleanup-feedback-wanted-etc?cb=1 the jrg has eliminated questions tagged with [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug).

I would like to request blacklisting of this tag, to begin now and to last until the End of Time Itself.

Please vote on this, since there's now voting points on it.

Comment: AMEN BROTHER. AMEN. I spent 5 hours over two days (approximately) retagging the ~270 questions in there.

Comment: crash and freeze too?

Comment: @JorgeCastro lets do this all separately, since I'm about to do those.

Comment: That's why i only mentioned [tag:bug], @JorgeCastro

Comment: This needs to be bumped up and voted so we can start negotiating with the SE community again. The tag is clean and does not require much attention but keep a eye out for new questions with this tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, the tag should be blacklisted.

I cannot see any useful use of the tag, so I propose that:

- Community members go through the tag page and on relevant posts replace it with [packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packages), [package-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package-management) or [debug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/debug), or other relevant tag.
- After this is completed, all other uses of the bug tag are removed from posts where it is not relevant to use them.
- The bug tag is blacklisted so it cannot be used.

Answer (score -2):

### No! Do not blacklist the tag!

I think the tag is useful and should not be blacklisted.

<sub>Please edit this and include any reasoning behind your thoughts.</sub>

Comment: If you vote up it means that you do not want to see the tag `bug` blacklisted. I my mind I cannot see why that tag should exist in the first place, but, if you disagree, you should edit this answer with some reasoning why the tag should not be blacklisted.

Comment: Most problems users have with Ubuntu are bugs. Also, questions reloated to bug reporting could use the tag.

Comment: @RobinJ bugs do not belong here, they are issues that need to solved with packages and should be reported in launchpad.net as such. Ask Ubuntu does not solve bugs, they are off topic for this site. Please read the FAQ and re-evaluate your position here.

Comment: So basically you're saying that all the graphic card problems don't belong here? Because 99% of them are caused by buggy drivers and buggy Compiz. Also, the bug tag can be usefull for questions like "What should I include in this bug report?".

Comment: @RobinJ There is a reason the are called closed source drivers and there is a reason launchpad exists. Questions like "which version of X driver do you recommend for my situation" are perfectly valid and do not need a bug tag, "please fix my bugged out driver" questions will be closed since we do not maintain of give fixes to software here, those should be redirected to lauchpad. Any thing that says bug or uses the tag bug, 99% of the times does not belong here or if valid should be edited to remove the tag from the question.

Comment: Then you are left with `Also, the bug tag can be usefull for questions like "What should I include in this bug report?"` questions that should not have the tag on them, instead they should use the [bug-reporting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug-reporting) tag.

Comment: If you just close questions related to buggy grapĥic card drivers, you'd immediately close about 20% of the questions on here, as it's the biggest cause of trouble appart from Wubi.
Ubuntu can't be used fluently without graphic card drivers.

Comment: @RobinJ That is your opinion, even so I do not know how can you fit the tag bug in to a graphics card drivers question, those at best should be marked with [tag:graphics] and [tag:driver]. Add _bug_ to a question and it means anything about everything, it does not relate to a specific situation, if you are following the tag as a favorite it does not sort anything at all, thus defeating the function of a tag.

Comment: Someone actually just voted down the "yes" answer and the "no" answer has 0 = +2 + (-2) votes.  I fear some people are misunderstanding and effectively voting twice here.