# Should we blacklist the freeze tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-block-request

The wiki of [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze) says:

> Do not use. This tag is in process of removal. If your software is
>   freezing then you likely need to file a bug, as freeze problems are
>   usually off topic here and will likely be closed.

I feel this is similar to the bug or error tags, both of which were blacklisted:

- http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5888/158442
- http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3386/158442

---

On a related note, we have a [frozen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/frozen) tag, which I just emptied - it should be nuked too (probably as a synonym).

Comment: We've trying to remove those tags since '12 http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3343/summer-cleanup-feedback-wanted-etc, tried again in '14 http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8911/169736

Comment: `If your software is freezing then you likely need to file a bug` Sometimes a workaround is what's needed. I recall a really nasty glitch that would render the system frozen sometimes, or other times simply unusable. It had to do with Chromium hardware acceleration, which could be disabled. So my #1 worst problem while using Ubuntu related to a freeze, and was solved by Ask Ubuntu. Not saying this tag should necessarily stay, but the description seems a bit off. If the tag is being misused, then by all means remove it.

Comment: @Nateowami er... that's a perfect example of a bug report. HWA not working with a X graphics card should be addressed by developers, by either explicitly disabling HWA with that graphic card or fixing their implementation so it works with that graphic card.

Comment: @Braiam I definitely agree it's a bug, but the fact is it *wasn't* addressed in several years (perhaps it has been by now, I don't know, it wasn't that long ago I had the problem). My point being that sometimes bugs, in this case a system freeze, have an easy workaround, so I think bugs are sometimes on topic, if the goal is to find a workaround.