# What to do about crash and freeze tags?

Tags: discussion, cleanup

Both [crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/crash) and [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze) are mostly all bug reports, most of which aren't diagnosable. iirc at one time we were in the process of blacklisting these, did we end up not wanting to do that?

Comment: Here's a previous Q about freeze: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14878/should-we-blacklist-the-freeze-tag. Couldn't find one specific to crash, although it was mentioned in several "tag cleanup" Qs.

Comment: [We should provide torches and pitchforks for the lazy](http://askubuntu.com/review/close/559822?filter-tags=freeze+crash)

Comment: BTW, I vote on these on batches, if someone is willing to help, just ping me. Maybe we could figure out something like the SOCVR room.