# We need a central list of canonical answers or best answers for oft-seen question

Tags: feature-request, answers, canonical-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are common canonical questions for our site?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3053/what-are-common-canonical-questions-for-our-site)

When a user posts a question about, for instance, [Ubuntu freezing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179421/ubuntu-10-04-freezes-unexpectedly), it would be useful to have a page that list the most common questions, and the answers that should be linked to.

So under "Freezing", there would be a link to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes).

It's just a wild idea, but I think it could actually be useful.

Comment: See also, the script for pulling all dupe targets from the dumps here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3317/finding-questions-that-other-questions-have-been-closed-as-a-dupe-of/3370#3370