# My question and answers are being changed without explanation by another user

Tags: support, editing, best-practice

I asked a question, and it got a lot of answers. Two of which were better than the others. Now, I believe both the question and the best answers are being stripped of essential details. I rolled back the changes once with comments, and the editor simply changed it back without comment.

I asked the question because there wasn't anything like it and now a editor wants to make it generic.

Here's the link to the question under discussion:

- [Which hard disk drive is which?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27997/which-hard-disk-drive-is-which)

Comment: Remember, you can always leave a small note to editors within `<sub></sub>` tags, within your post.

Answer (score 5):

The editor is only trying to make your question better.

1. "I am a lazy bum" this states that you are not willing to try reasonable solutions, and people will avoid trying to answer your question because of it.
2. Were these "Rules" part of a bounty you offered, and now are irrelevant to the question. Making suggestions that you perfer a Gui or terminal solution is a good thing, but making "rules" that bar answers is not a good thing. Possibally your question would be better suited in better explaining your situation.

Sample more friendly version of your question using the "rules" as part of your question.

> "I have server with several disks, In opening my case I can see the
>   labels of each of the drives (or if you can't see the labels with out
>   removing them, say that- In a later comment I see you said this "but
>   in my scenario the disks are crammed in a holder that blocks the
>   sticker from view. The best I can do is trace the cables. " add that
>   to the question!) I can where each of the SATA disks is plugged in to
>   on the motherboard.
>
> I want to know which hard disk drive corresponds to which device path
>   (`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc). It's trivial to match the hard disk
>   stats (brand, size) with the dev path, but I want more.
>
> I want to know which drive is which inside my case. What's a good way
>   to go about getting this info? Are there good Command line and Graphical interface tools?

So you see that with just a little bit of work we can make this a better question for everyone.

I fully support the edit that @Jacob Johan Edwards did.

Regardless, the "bonus" part should be removed as it is specific to the bounty and accepted answer which is now over.

Answer (score 2):

Can I make a friendly suggestion? Maybe it would be best if **you** edit the question (and answers) to be more of a *canonical question*. After reading [this related post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3053/12864), I suspect this is the goal (guessing, not speaking for Jacob).

I say this because while the question and answers are fun to read and contain some humorous bits, it is somewhat chatty. This isn't automatically a bad thing, but it puts the many non-native English speakers here at a disadvantage. It also requires more reading comprehension to sort through all those words. The bonus came and went, references to it aren't really critical to explain. The answer awarded the bonus is great and deserved a bonus anyway.

Since you are the original author, I think you are the one who could best re-make the question simpler, clearer, and preserve your original goals in asking it.

Answer (score 1):

Until Jacob has a chance to explain himself, I've locked the post for the next 24 hours.