# What is the official canonical questions list nowadays?

Tags: discussion

We have http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3053/what-are-common-canonical-questions-for-our-site, but I'm not sure how up-to-date that is. Also, there's the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=faq). Which one have we said is the official canonical questions list?

Also: can we feature that more prominently on main? Maybe a link (you may want to check canonical questions instead of answering) below the answer box?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the questions in [What are common canonical questions for our site?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3053/what-are-common-canonical-questions-for-our-site) still apply today but there are some that have appeared by either doing some cleanup on the site or by using the cleanup system by Oli and the stat queries by Jorge. Here are some of the ones I find very good and others I worked to make them solve the same common issues.

Since I worked as a teacher for a couple of years, almost all of the questions here were a lifesaver since they saved me a lot of time explaining the same questions over and over again and some I created because there was the need and the repeated questions:

[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

[How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

[How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

[How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services)

[What is Ubuntu Touch (Ubuntu for Phones)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-touch-ubuntu-for-phones)

[What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

[How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers)

[Why is Wayland better?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11537/why-is-wayland-better)

[How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

[How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171914/sharing-your-internet-connection-with-other-pcs-and-phones)

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

[How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

[How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)

[How to connect and disconnect to a network manually in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal)

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

[How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

[What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

[How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work)

[How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)

[How to check hard disk performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87035/how-to-check-hard-disk-performance)

[What's the difference between Google Chrome and/or Chromium? What are the advantages/disadvantages to each?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant)

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

[How can I remove Amazon search results from the dash or disable the feature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash)

[How do I configure juju for local usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage)

Comment: Surely you can update the original and close this as dupe?

Comment: @JorgeCastro Done. You are right.