# Do we need a "Will Ubuntu work for X model PC?" question?

Tags: discussion, review

This is related to: [Do we need thousand of "dumb questions"? or can we just duplicate them to more general answer?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7613/do-we-need-thousand-of-dumb-questions-or-can-we-just-duplicate-them-to-more-g)

I know newbies will be always newbies, and there isn't enough users to deal with them (the [eternal September](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) rings a bell for anyone? Usenet?). So, to take care of the influx I'm proposing several "newbies questions" like the one mentioned in the title so we can dump the new questions that arrives that could be very well answered with these questions.

This also brings another issue and it's that the Close Queue is growing at accelerated pace (last week I was about 200 reviews, today hover over 300 and menacing to grow more). I've seen that in the 3-4 months (I got my 3k rep Aug 28) I've made more reviews than most of seniors members (I know some use their votes outside the queue which is cool). If you have couple of votes left spare 30 mins in the review queue since we shouldn't need the Mods step in the queue for something that the 320+-ish > 3K rep users can handle in a day or two. Assuming:

```
   (320 * 20)     >      (150 * 5)
  Users * Reviews   Items * Votes needed
```

Remember that shopping recommendation is off-topic so do not dupe questions of these kind, but flag them as off-topic.