# Where are the canonical questions for creating a Ubuntu Live USB?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

Apparently we can never find the duplicate question and now we have about 40 questions (maybe I am exaggerating...) about creating Live USB in Windows, Mac OS and Linux... could someone hunt them down and do a nice list below... Thanks :D

Comment: Couldn't this be added [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3053/what-are-common-canonical-questions-for-our-site)? I think it'd be better to keep a big list in one place than in separate questions.

Comment: @minerz029 no, it isn't there, and that list is not maintained since nov. Doesn't include none of what I'm asking. I prefer localized lists rather than big list where I can't find anything.

Comment: @Braiam Though often control+f gets the job done.

Comment: @Jeremy my Ctrl is mapped to Alt, and F is mapped to F4 ;).

Answer (score 4):

#### Create a Ubuntu Live USB in Windows:

[How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick-in-linux)

#### Create a Ubuntu Live USB in Linux:

[How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/372607/169736)

#### Create a Ubuntu Live USB in Mac OS:

[How do I create an Ubuntu live USB using a Mac?](https://askubuntu.com/q/86/169736)

#### Create a Ubuntu Live USB in Ubuntu:

[How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276470/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/276481#276481)

[USB Creator](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) is in the menu as of 12.04.

Comment: Missing the Linux & Ubuntu links...

Comment: or maybe he's waiting for someone to add it ?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I haven't found those...

Comment: @TommyAriaPradana yeah, I was asking where they are as I haven't found them ;)

Comment: How about this one? http://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal/376430#376430 The accepted answer is a Linux answer and not distro-dependent since it's terminal commands

Comment: usb-creator-gtk is standard with ubuntu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick It works splendidly with ubuntu.

Comment: I think the best reference for "create Ubuntu LiveUSB on Ubuntu" would be the official instructions here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu. Until someone makes a canonical question which we can dupe to, of course.