# Use of Anaconda/Alternate python for AI and data analysis

Tags: discussion

It seems to me that users often face problems when they tinker with system python, such as

[Problem updating 20.04 - python3.7 errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405480/problem-updating-20-04-python3-7-errors/1406471),

who attempted to install python3.7 to use AI/ML and ended up with a broken apt. Shall we recommend users to use Anaconda or compile python from source in their home folder?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure this question belongs on meta! It could be rephrased a bit and placed on the main site.

Comment: ok, will do that.

Comment: See also [this request](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19927/1438484) for a canonical question regarding "I messed with Python and broke _____". While we should probobly have something for people that want to change something, having a general (canonical) post for people that _already_ broke their system by messing with Python would be good. I'd fully support making [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications) the canonical dupe target

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding an answer to use Anaconda for setting up multiple python versions is fine.

However, I would be against making it a canonical answer. There are multiple ways to install different python versions. Deciding on Anaconda being the go-to answer doesn't seem right, especially since it's not part of the official repositories offered and reviewed by Canonical.

The official way to install Anaconda is to run a script you [download](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) from their site.

I understand it's a popular product, but running any external script is dangerous when you are not careful. Take the popular bumblebee project, for example, that at some point had an `rm` that [wiped the whole system](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/issues/123).

Comment: Fascinating script disaster you have referenced! The change introduced all the way back in 2011 was: `rm -rf /usr /lib/nvidia-current/xorg/xorg` whereas it should have been `rm -rf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/xorg`. One space that should not have been there...

Comment: Wow! Must be one of the worst bugs ever! 