# Searchbox during flagging inept results

Tags: support, flagging

I often have the problem when I flag something as duplicate and try to search in this searchbox I get no hits. But when I use the same keywords in my google search I find what I'm after.

With search box I mean

[image: searchbox]

Comment: Even I face this problem too..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah.. I usually flag as dupe from prior knowledge, and then use the main search or search engine to get the results.

There's also this thread with [common canonical questions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3053/what-are-common-canonical-questions-for-our-site), which can help.

But you're right, the search box in flag as dupe is rather useless - I don't know if anything can be done about it.

Comment: One thing that occasionally helps slightly is to restrict results by score, by typing for example *score:10* for questions with a score of 10 or more

Comment: Still, atleast there should be an option to paste it as a URL, right?

Comment: Yes, you can paste an URL into the box - isn't this working for you?

Comment: Yes on Notebook but not on mobile it's too unpredictable.