# Ask Ubuntu version of "Oh The Horror" Hat Club anybody?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

So, I was reading around the Stack Exchange network and came across this (easily googleable) question: [“Oh The Horror” Hat Club](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/oh-the-horror-hat-club)

Anyone want to give this a go?

From the page:

> 41 people join in.
>
> Each person upvotes every answer, other than theirs, to this question.
>
> Once we have 41 answers and votes, I will systematically accept each
>   answer in turn.
>
> 41 people get the ["Oh the Horror"](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/oh-the-horror) hat.
>
> Easy.

Don't blame me, I just thought this would be fun to try.

Comment: I don't think it will work on Meta.

Comment: @NathanOsman The "Oh the horror" hat is a meta hat.. I personally kinda like the idea, since no one ever upvotes much around here. At least, not up to 40.

Comment: @NathanOsman It worked on the english meta?

Comment: @Seth I see your point. It seems very un-friendly around here some times. :D

Comment: Ah, okay. Never mind then.

Comment: @NathanOsman Aren't you going to join in on the fun?

Comment: I'd like to try, but the thing is, the [Guru badge](http://meta.askubuntu.com/help/badges/18/guru) which gets you this hat has only been awarded once. To [Oli](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) for [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1900/is-jorge-castro-a-robot/1902#1902)

Comment: @minerz029 Well, they did it in the English Language SE Meta, so why not here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, we didn't make the 40 upvotes per question, not even close, and didn't have 41 participants.

Thanks for everyone's participation, and hopefully we can pull something off next year!

Kudos to @Minerz029 for supplying this comment: [Ask Ubuntu version of "Oh The Horror" Hat Club anybody?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7950/ask-ubuntu-version-of-oh-the-horror-hat-club-anybody?cb=1#comment14046_7966)

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Well, a hat is a hat, isn't it?

Comment: Good point! :D It hath been upvoted

Comment: Ping reminder to upvote new answers here!

Comment: Ping reminder to upvote new answers here!

Comment: Seriously! I make a point and it doesn't get upvoted :P Bother it all.

Answer (score 15):

MY KINGDOM FOR A HAT!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I love your point on this answer! Upvote!

Comment: Ping reminder to upvote new answers here!

Comment: Ping reminder to upvote new answers here!

Answer (score 15):

41 people? We'll never gonna make it!

Comment: Ping reminder to upvote new answers here!

Comment: Ping reminder to upvote new answers here!

Answer (score 15):

> Teddy said it was a hat,
>
> So I put it on.
>
> Now Dad is saying,
>
> "Where the heck's
>
> the toilet plunger gone?"

rip ss

Comment: Ping reminder to upvote new answers here!

Comment: Ping reminder to upvote new answers here!

Answer (score 15):

It's certainly worth a try, though whether 41 people will answer before Saturday is questionable.
We'll all get the Guru badge anyway!

Some random HTML to cheer you up:

1. Coffee
2. Tea
3. Milk

Comment: Well, we can try! We have 5...

Comment: Ping reminder to upvote new answers here!

Answer (score 15):

Wish I'd seen that post sooner, but here are some stats...

**As of January 1st, 2014 UTC 6:00...**

> We have 6 answers (counting mine) and of those...
>
> - @Guntbert's has been upvoted 9 times
> - @Braiam's has been upvoted 6 times
> - @Eric's has been upvoted 4 times
> - @djeikyb's has been upvoted 2 times
> - @minerz029's has been upvoted 1 times
> - @rpiawesomeness's has been upvoted 0 times
>
> **At this rate:**
>
> - *Answers* = 6/41  -- 6 a day would take 6 days, too long.
>
>   11 a day would take ~3.7 days.
> - *Upvotes currently possible from answering participants*: 6 plus outside votes (as seen on Gunbert's answer)

Don't forget to check back and upvote new ones!

Comment: Should we be updating this? The timeline is [available here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/7950/timeline) if anyone is curious. We got 102 up votes on this question + answers, and 9 answers yesterday :) We might actually pull this off...

Answer (score 14):

Hats? Looks like hair to me...

Comment: Ping reminder to upvote new answers here!

Answer (score 14):

Well, I wanted to put something catchy or funny here, but couldn't think of anything. So here I am. Not funny.

Answer (score 14):

We won't get enough people, but might as well try.

Answer (score 14):

I already posted in the other thread, can I post here too?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that.. the more votes you can get us the better!

Answer (score 13):

"Why else would man want to live more if not to take care of others." Erasmus (freely translated).

Happy newyear folks!

Comment: Ping reminder to upvote new answers here!

Answer (score 13):

A group participation hat?  That could work...

Answer (score 13):

Let me also throw my hat in the ring...